# Sound Frequency detecting?

Tags: c#, php, audio, speech-recognition, frequency

What is the solution to detect specific words from audio file?

I have a lot of audio file (same codec) and each file is only about 15 seconds long.  (Note: all audio files are the same person / same accent)

For example:

**test1.mp3** play `Hello Tom, what are you doing today?`

**test2.mp3** play `Hello Paul, what are you doing today?`

**test3.mp3** play `Good morning John - It is lovely weather today`

I need a way to detect **lovely weather** or **what are you** words from each audio file.

I may have 100 audio files say "what are you doing today" and other files say "what are you doing today?"  - I just need to know what what the status/type of each file are..

What is the solution to check frequency bits exist rather than using Voice Recognition tool.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what your research has turned up so far?

Comment: `What is the solution to this?` - The solution is to not use PHP. It is not a good choice for this sort of thing, it requires a *lot* of low level mathematical operations and PHP is not very efficient for this.

Comment: I agree with Dave. You might find some ideas to handle your problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23592/how-do-i-search-content-within-audio-files-streams

Comment: look for speech recognition programs/libraries/web services in other languages, then call them via the command line. You won't find speech recognition stuff directly in php.

Comment: I should think by _using_ PHP, the OP means they are happy to use libraries/modules from PHP but not necessarily written in PHP `:)`.

Comment: speech recognition is not a good solution and it is too complex. Ok what is alternative to PHP?  ... I may have like 20 audio files say "what are you doing today?" and 34 files say "It is lovely weather today" - I just need to detect what the status of each file so I can flag it to the database.

Comment: If you only need to do this with a couple of files, you might want to try the google speech api, here's a good article on how to use it with perl examples http://mikepultz.com/2011/03/accessing-google-speech-api-chrome-11/ I've actually done this with curl and php. You just need to POST the sound file in the correct format

Comment: consider changing the title to speech recognition.

Comment: PHP is the wrong choice for this task.

Comment: @marcelog I have couples thousands of files :) All audio have identical same sentence and voice. I just a way to detect what the status of each file are.

Comment: @halfer I am looking for a solution to check if the needle frequency bits exist on the haystack frequency bits. It is simple as that.

Comment: @user791022 - not sure which of my comments you're responding to. I presume the second one, in which I was defending your use of the PHP tag?

Comment: No, no, it is **not** as simple as that

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6351055/90236

Comment: Misleading title.  Word detection/recognition is a different topic from frequency detecting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Text-to-speech (voice generation) and speech-to-text (voice recognition) APIs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348770/text-to-speech-voice-generation-and-speech-to-text-voice-recognition-apis)

Comment: @user791022: if files have same sentence and voice, what's different about them?  Are they identical files, or many instances of the same speaker saying the same thing?  Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You are essentially asking "How can I do general purpose speech recognition"?

The solutions are:

If your platform provides speech-recognition out of the box, use that. Microsoft Windows does, for example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323805.aspx

If your platform does not, then you need to integrate a third party speech recognition package, such as Lernaut & Hauspie (now Nuance), Dragon, etc. This will likely involve paying money.

**Edit:** I have flagged this as a duplicate of [Text-to-speech (voice generation) and speech-to-text (voice recognition) APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348770/text-to-speech-voice-generation-and-speech-to-text-voice-recognition-apis), which has a comprehensive answer to "how can I do speech recognition".